# How to make time function update itself?

Tags: javascript, function, time, setinterval

When I load this in a browser it'll show the time it was when page was fully loaded, but won't update itself every second. How do I do this?

```
var h = date.getHours();   if(h<10) h = "0"+h;
var m = date.getMinutes(); if(m<10) m = "0"+m;
var s = date.getSeconds(); if(s<10) s = "0"+s;
document.write(h + " : " + m + " : " + s);
```

Comment: what about setInterval?

Comment: `setInterval`​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Try this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: @LuigiSiri Don't use w3schools **ever** `>:(`

Comment: May I ask, Why? @Doorknob

Comment: @LuigiSiri: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: That's a good point. @Janus Troelsen

Answer (score 7):

Use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(clock, 1000);

function clock() {
   var date = new Date();
   var h = date.getHours();   if(h<10) h = "0"+h;
   var m = date.getMinutes(); if(m<10) m = "0"+m;
   var s = date.getSeconds(); if(s<10) s = "0"+s;
   document.write(h + " : " + m + " : " + s);
}
```

Although you probably want to update a `HTML` element rather than `document.write` to the page every second.

http://jsfiddle.net/bQNwJ/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up in a function and let it call itself:

```
everysecond=1000; // milliseconds
function showCurrentTime(){
    /*do your timing stuff here */
    if(someConditionIsntMet) setTimeout(showCurrentTime, everysecond)
}
```

Comment: very bad. set interval is better for this

Comment: No. SetIntervall is not better. It is Ongoing. With the selfinvoking function, you have the possibility to abort at a given condition. there is no easy way to abort setInterval

Comment: @Lilith2k3 ...yes it is. What kind of logic makes you think this is better?

Comment: @Doorknob: Like he said, it's more flexible. You can build setInterval easily from setTimeout, but not the other way around.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen `var intr = setInterval(dostuff, 1000); clearInterval(intr)`

Comment: In my eyes, setInterval is for this kind of jobs an AntiPattern.

Comment: `setInterval` is for repeating things! **Period.** That's what it does, that's what it was made to do. `setTimeout` is for delays, *that's the only thing it should be used for*. And about aborting it? `var intr = setInterval(dostuff, 1000); clearInterval(intr)`.

Comment: `setInterval` is worse for this purpose because it is not dependent on the time it takes to run the function. You don't wanna update simultaneously if it takes a long time to run the function. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/309483 PERIOOOOOOOOOOOOOD